# What's wrong with this arrow symbol?

Tags: c#

I have the following file in c# and I am using VS 2013 but I get stuck at the "=>" symbol, VS always asks for a ";" right after the "=>" symbol in the following file:

```
namespace GlobomanticsElectricCompany.BillProcessor.Models
{
    public class ContactInfo
    {
        public string Line1 { get; set; }
        public string Line2 { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Zip { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string CityStateZip => $"{City}, {State} {Zip}";
    }
}
```

What should I do to make VS to recognize that "=>" symbol?

Comment: You need C# > 6 to use `=>`

Comment: You're going to have a similar problem with that string interpolation as well.

Comment: To Change the C# version, go to the Project, Right Click, Properties, under the Build tab at the button, you will find Advanced, Open it and choose the correct Language Version

Comment: @Nekeniehl C# 6 is not available in VS2013.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto My mistake, sorry. This is indeed a pure C# question.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. I know what's wrong with it now :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this issue recently; I don't believe the => syntax is valid in that version of Visual Studio. Try to define it like this instead:

```
    public string CityStateZip
    {
        get
        {
            return City + " , " + State + " " + Zip;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You may need to throw some extra spaces in there, or maybe use good old String.Format

Comment: The feature is called Expression bodied members and is available from c# 6.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing thank you, silly thing to miss

Comment: Thanks Nick, it works like a charm. :-)